# Numbers stored in memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, integer

So I am reading about networking in Python and the section is explaining about the big and little endian. I understand that when some data is bigger than one byte they show the order in which the data should be read from memory to make sense to the user, but here is what I don't understand. The book says that we can see how the number 4253 is stored in memory by calling the hex function :

```
>>> hex(4253)
'0x109d'
```

and then it says that every digit in the hex value is 4 bits, so 2 digits would be one byte. Until now everything is clear the value `0x109d` is 2 bytes as shows the binary representation of the number `4253` which is `0001000010011101`. But then it gives an example with the struct module's pack and unpack methods and it turns out that the value `4253` is 4 bytes. Here comes the confusion, why is the value 4 bytes ? What do the 2 empty bytes do ?

```
>>> struct.pack('<i',4253)
'\x9d\x10\x00\x00'
```

Comment: The format string determines the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly given in the [documentation of format characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) -

> The ‘Standard size’ column refers to the size of the packed value in bytes when using standard size
>
> **i**  -  int  -  integer  -  4  -  (3)

In the above `4` is the standard size for that format in bytes.

The format string (first argument to `struct.pack` ) determines how many bytes it would take.